# CSS Cascading Issue

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a project and my CSS doesn't seem to be cascading correctly.

I have set some styles (mainly the color property) at the HTML tag level. However it is not cascading to the rest of my elements, specifically the .logo class, but also some other classes.  Can anyone help me understand why this is happening?

Here is my code:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: seashell;
  background-color: black;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 22px;
  opacity: 0.9;
}


/* Header and Nav Bar */

.header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  height: 69px;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  border-bottom: 1px solid seashell;
}

.logo {
  margin-left: 10px;
  max-height: 50px;
}

.navigation {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
}

.navigation a {
  padding: 15px;
}

.navigation a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}


/******* Hero *******/

#hero {
  background-image: url(/Images/img-mission-background.webp);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
  top: 70px;
  height: 700px;
  width: 1200px;
  margin: auto;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

#hero h2,
h4 {
  padding: 12px;
}


/***** Content ******/

.content {
  position: relative;
  top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!--******* Header ******* -->
<header class="header">
  <img src="/Images/img-tea-cozy-logo.webp" alt="Tea Cozy Logo" class="logo" />
  <ul class="navigation">
    <li><a href="#">Mission</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Featured Tea</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Locations</a></li>
  </ul>
</header>
<section id="hero">
  <h2>Our Mission</h2>
  <h4>
    Handpicked, Artisanally Curated, Free Range, Sustainable, Small Batch, Fair Trade, Organic Tea
  </h4>
</section>
<section class="content">
  <h1>Tea of the Month</h1>
</section>
```

Comment: Can you be more specific as to exactly isn't working properly?

Comment: The `color` property cascades just fine for me in your snippet. It's not clear what isn't working to your specification. Voting to close as not reproducible.

Comment: Is your problem that the text in the header is not the ``seashell`` color? You have to set that manually - the default styling overrides the ``html`` inheritance.

Comment: Yes, the logo and the Nav items are not inheriting the seashell color. The text over the background image is also supposed have a background color of black, which I set int he HTML selector.  Does the browser override all CSS properties declared on the HTML element?